# Cannot properly connect function with service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, swagger

I'm trying to get the profile for a single patient from the endpoint where I should send the Id of the patient in order to get back the details.

my service.ts:

```
public patientCard(patientId: string) {
    return this._httpClient
      .get(
        this._api_url +
          "patient/single?patientId=" +
          encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(patientId))
      )
      .pipe(
        map((data: APIResult<Array<PatientObject>>) => {
          console.log("Response: -->", data.result);
          return data.result;
        }),
        catchError(this._handleError)
      );
  }
```

Here is my component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.patientCard(patientId);
  }

  patientCard(patientId: string) {
    return this.appService
      .patientCard(this.patientId)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.patientId = data.patientId;
      });
  }
```

my model.ts:

```
export class PatientObject {
  constructor(
    public patientId?: string,
    public name?: string,
    public surname?: string,
    public dob?: string | Date,
    public note?: string,
    public isFzo?: boolean,
    public gender?: string,
    public embg?: string,
    public phoneNumber?: string,
    public contactEmail?: string
  ) {}
}
```

Here is what I have done so far. Check my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j7rrkf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I'm still a rookie, so have that in mind :D

Thanks in advance for all the help!!!

Comment: how do you get patientId inside ngOnInit ?

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help. I know that I should pass there the patientId but don't know where to get it from. I tried with this.appservice too but with no luck.

Comment: add the route used to reach this component

Comment: can you tell me how to do that, because I have the Id in the route, how can I get it from there and send it to the function?

Comment: how does your route look show the routing.module.ts file?

Comment: This is the service I use for the route:
```
public searchPatient(name: string) {
    return this._httpClient
      .get(this._api_url + `patient/search/by/name?name=${name}`)
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
          return data.result;
        }),
        catchError(this._handleError)
      );
  }
```
and here is the route I use with query params:

```
routerLink="/patient/card"
              [queryParams]="{ patientId: row.patientId }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

///////////Assuming Your Route is //////////

```
{  path:"yourRout/:id", component:yourComponent}
```

////////Component.ts file//////////////

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

patientInfo:PatientObject;
patientId:string;

  constructor(private appService:appService,
    private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
    
    

    ngOnInit(): void 
    {   //get the patientId from the route
        
         //updated this code start
         this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params)=>
         {
              this.patientId = params['patientId']; 
              this.patientCard();   
        })
          //updated this code end
    }
    
    
    patientCard() 
    {
          this.appService
          .patientCard(this.patientId)
          .subscribe((data: any) => 
          {
              //here you may get the patient info
              this.patientInfo = data;
              //this.patientId = data.patientId;
          });
    }
```

Comment: This is what i keep getting. I tried so many options, but still this is the result I get:
**http://api.dentist.techup.me/patient/single?patientId=undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)**
**patient.service.ts:116 Backend returned code 500, body was: [object Object]
**

Comment: here in the api "undefined" patientId is being passed because actually in your code you were not passing patientId properly.

Comment: I tried the code above and still got the same error. Even when I try to console.out the patientId from the params it gives me back an undefined data.

Comment: this is the reason why i am asking to show the route file.

Comment: does your route look like {  path:"yourRout/:id", component:yourComponent}  ?

Comment: here is my patient-routes.module.ts:

`const patientRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: PatientComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: PatientTableComponent
      },
     
      {
        path: "card",
        component: PatientCardComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];`

Comment: here in your route there is no "id" parameter only

Comment: i'm passing the Id in the HTML: 
routerLink="/patient/card" [queryParams]="{ patientId: row.patientId }"

Comment: insted of "this.route.params" just use "this.route.queryParams" have edited the code

Comment: thank you for all your help!!! 
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.patientId = params["patientId"];
      console.log(params);
      this.patientCard(JSON.stringify(this.patientId));
    }); 

SOLVED my problem. Thank you again for all you have done for me